# Mulesoft Dataweave map object to array

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

In Mulesoft Dataweave I want to map an object to an array.


Input:

```
[
  {
     "id": 12, "name": "sun", "age": 25
  },
  {
     "id": 13, "name": "moon", "age": 25
  },
  {
     "id": 14, "name": "pluto", "age": 28
  },
  ..... etc.
]
```

And the result must be this:

[12,13,14]

I have tried it with a map but it does not wor because it seems I am tied to using json objects.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question with valid JSON - the keys have to be wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't even need to map:

input:

```json
[
  {
     "id": 12, "name": "sun", "age": 25
  },
  {
     "id": 13, "name": "moon", "age": 25
  },
  {
     "id": 14, "name": "pluto", "age": 28
  }
]
```

dataweave:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.id
```

if you wanted to map though you could simply do:

`payload map $.id`

`payload map (item) -> item.id`

`payload map (item) -> (item.id)`

`map(payload, (item) -> item.id))`

all of which would give you the same result

If you were trying: `payload map { ...`, you'd get an object back out because of the `{`.

output:

```json
[
  12,
  13,
  14
]
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is what I need !